# Mysql: Multiply the number of rows by registration column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with specific information regarding vehicles. However each row may represent many vehicles. The goal is to select an output with each row to be 1 registration.

The simplified code is:

```
select country, year,  manufacturer, model, registrations, engine_power from cars;
```

Output

[image: Output]

Desired Output

[image: Desired Output]

The version is 10.1.32-MariaDB.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: innodb_version 5.6.38-83.0 ,
protocol_version 10 ,
version 10.1.32-MariaDB

Answer (score 2):

Try with recursive CTE. here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=da34e97720dc7e930f4b080443051138).

```
with recursive cte as
(
    select 
          manufacturer,
          model,
          registrations,
          1 as num,
         engine_power
    from cars

    union all

    select 
          manufacturer,
          model,
          registrations - 1,
          1,
          engine_power
    from cte
    where registrations > 1
)

select 
  manufacturer,
  model,
  num as registrations,
  engine_power
from cte
order by
  model
```

Output:

```
 manufacturer    model        registrations   engine_power
----------------------------------------------------------
 audi ag A3    SPORTBACK E-TRON       1             110
 audi ag A3    SPORTBACK E-TRON       1             110
 audi ag A3    SPORTBACK E-TRON       1             110
 DAIMLER AG    C 350 E                1             155
 DAIMLER AG    C 350 E                1             155
 DAIMLER AG    GLC 350 4MATIC         1             155
```

Comment: Thank you for you time and answer. However it seems that Recursive WITH has been supported since MariaDB 10.2.2. My version is 10.1.32-MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

If `Recursive CTE` is not supported, you can try with `joins`

```
SELECT c.manufacturer, c.model, 1,c.engine_power
FROM cars c 
JOIN ( SELECT 1 as num 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 2 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 3
     ) n
ON c.registrations >= n.num
```

This is just a sample and will only work upto 3 registration. Post that you have to either increase the `UNION ALL` or create a number table for the max count

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and your time. Unfortunately there are cases with many more registrations (e.g. 250)

Comment: In that case, you can create a number table. and Use the `table` instead of `UNION`. [Check this LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=871b58c7b6012d127012ccf93b3951fe). I have provided demo there @ArisMist